# Sum the rows of a pandas dataframe grouping by the last n dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
Ac   |Type   |Id    |Date       |Value     |Pe    |
---------------------------------------------------
Debt |Other  |DE    |2017-12-31 |5         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2018-03-31 |4         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2018-06-30 |3         |12M   |
Debt |Other  |DE    |2018-09-30 |2         |12M   |
Debt |Other  |DE    |2018-12-31 |5         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2019-03-31 |6         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2019-06-30 |1         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2019-09-30 |5         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2019-12-31 |2         |12M   |
Debt |Other  |DE    |2020-03-31 |3         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2019-06-30 |4         |12M   |
```

And, grouping by year, I need to add the 4 previous values of the column 'Value' with respect to that year, having something like this:

```
Ac   |Type   |Id    |Date       |Value     |Pe    |
---------------------------------------------------
Debt |Other  |DE    |2017-12-31 |5         |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2018-12-31 |4+3+2+5   |12M   | 
Debt |Other  |DE    |2019-12-31 |6+1+5+2   |12M   |
Debt |Other  |DE    |2020-09-30 |5+2+3+4   |12M   |
```

With the following conditions:

1. if it is not possible to sum 3 previous dates because there are not 3 rows with previous dates, leave the one that is already there as in the case of the row with date 2017-12-31 in the example.
2. If the previous rows are not all in the same year, add the value column of those rows and leave in the 'Date' column the last date. As in the case of the row with date 2020-09-30 in the example

]Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Do you want the actual text `4+3+2+5 ` or the value 14 in the Value column?

Comment: The value, 14. I put it in this way just to explain that is the sum of the values in the 3 previous and the currentl row.

Comment: Why only 2 previous values `5` and `2` were captured for year `2020` ?

Comment: In fact there were captured also de values 6 for 2019-03-31 and 1 for 2019-06-30. But I need to sum strictly the last 4 values chronologically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row, sum the `Value` of the last *n* = 4 dates

```py
df["Value"] = df["Value"].rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum()
```

Then, only keep the last row of each year

```py
rows_to_keep = df["Date"].dt.year.drop_duplicates(keep="last").index
df = df.loc[rows_to_keep]
print(df)
```

Comment: The problem  in this line rows_to_keep = df["Date"].str[:4].drop_duplicates(keep="last").index is that it assume that my Date column is a string type columns, but is a datetime type column.

Comment: I solved adding a .astype(str) , giving this:                                                         
rows_to_keep = df["Date"].astype(str).str[:4].drop_duplicates(keep="last").index

Comment: You can also use `df["Date"].dt.year.drop_duplicates(keep="last")`